# Listar dados em um Activity

Tags: android, crud

Essa é minha primeira publicação no fórum, espero não estar infligindo nenhuma regra -.
Estou iniciando em programação *Android*, dai estou tentando desenvolver um *CRUD*. Até agora fiz o cadastro e a listagem, porém essa última insiste em dar erro mesmo o código estando aparentemente correto... (Está coerente com as instruções de sites como o *DevMidia*). Gostaria de ajuda para encontrar o que estou fazendo de errado, desde já agradeço! :)

CÓDIGO DA CLASSE BANCO:

```
public class Banco extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

static final String NOME_BANCO = "banco.db";
static final String TABELA = "pacientes";

static final String ID = "id";
static final String PACIENTE = "paciente";
static final String LEITO = "leito";

static final int VERSAO = 1;


public Banco(Context context) { // local do banco

    super(context,NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO);

}

@Override

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("" +
            "create table pacientes(id integer primary key autoincrement, paciente text not null" +
            ", leito text not null);");
}

@Override

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pacientes");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

CÓDIGO DO CRUD

```
public class CRUD {

 SQLiteDatabase db;
 Banco banco;

public CRUD (Context context){
            banco = new Banco(context);
}

public String insert(String paciente, String leito){
    //responsável por inserir
    ContentValues valores;
    long resultado;

    db=banco.getWritableDatabase();

    //gravar no banco
    valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put(Banco.PACIENTE, paciente);
    valores.put(Banco.LEITO, leito);

    resultado = db.insert(Banco.TABELA, null, valores);
    db.close();
    if (resultado ==-1)
        return "Erro ao inserir registro";
    else
        return "Cadastrado :)";
}

public Cursor carregaDados(){
    Cursor cursor;
    String campos[] = {banco.PACIENTE,banco.LEITO,banco.ID};

    db = banco.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.query(banco.TABELA, campos, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(cursor!=null)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    db.close();

    return cursor;
}
```

CÓDIGO DA LISTAGEM DOS DADOS

```
public class Consulta extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lista;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_consulta);

    CRUD crud = new CRUD (getBaseContext());
    Cursor cursor = crud.carregaDados();

    String [] nomecampos = new String [] {Banco.PACIENTE, Banco.LEITO,Banco.ID};

    int [] idViews = new int [] {R.id.idPaciente, R.id.idLeito,R.id.idId};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adaptador = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.formatador, cursor, nomecampos,idViews,0);
    lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listinha);
    lista.setAdapter(adaptador);
}
}
```

Comment: Qual erro exatamente ocorre? Aparece em algum lugar? Tente descrever mais o seu problema

Comment: Então amigo, não aparece nenhum erro explícito. Quando chamo o botão que tem o método de listar, o app simplesmente para de funcionar. Dai fiz alguns testes, e quando apago o conteúdo do método de listar e deixo o botão chamando apenas a activity vazia da listagem, o app roda normalmente, chamando a tela e tudo o mais. O que me leva a crer que há algum erro no código  da listagem propriamente dita

Comment: Entendi. Toda vez que você está desenvolvendo um aplicativo e eventualmente ele para de funcionar (e fecha sozinho), aparece uma exceção no logcat. Se você estiver usando o Android Studio, vai ter uma abinha no canto inferior, chamado Android Monitor. Ao abrir ele, você pode ver logs de debug, erro, etc. Nele deve aparecer a exceção que foi lançada, o que já ajudaria muito. Mas só vai aparecer se der o erro e você estiver com o logcat (no Android Monitor) aberto

Comment: Então se você puder atualizar a pergunta com esse log, que vai estar em vermelho...